Issues with CORS and OPTIONS Preflight Request in Nginx Proxy for Node.js Backend
I am currently working on setting up a microservices architecture for my application. My setup includes a frontend built with React, and backend services using Node.js and Express. I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy to route requests to the appropriate backend services.
However, I am encountering a CORS issue specifically with the preflight OPTIONS request. When I attempt to make a POST request from my frontend to the backend through Nginx, I receive a 405 Method Not Allowed error. The error indicates that the OPTIONS method is not allowed, even though I have configured Nginx to handle OPTIONS requests.
Here are the relevant details of my setup:
Nginx Configuration:
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log D:/programming/nginx-1.27.2/logs/access.log main;
    error_log D:/programming/nginx-1.27.2/logs/error.log warn;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location /api/auth/ {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
        }

        location /api/business/ {
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type, Authorization';
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5173;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

Backend Service Configuration (authService):
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();


mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI, { 
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization'],
    credentials: true
}));


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`Request method: ${req.method}, Request path: ${req.path}, Request body: ${JSON.stringify(req.body)}`);
    next();
});

app.options('*', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:5173');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Max-Age', 1728000);
    res.sendStatus(204);
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;// .env PORT=5000 

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`AuthService running on port ${PORT}`);
});


I have configured Nginx to handle CORS preflight requests by adding the necessary headers and allowing the OPTIONS method.

I have also configured my backend services to handle OPTIONS requests and return appropriate CORS headers.

When I send a POST request directly to my backend service using curl, it works correctly and returns the expected response.

However, when I send the same request through Nginx, I receive a 405 Method Not Allowed error for the OPTIONS preflight request.


I expected Nginx to properly forward the OPTIONS request to my backend service and receive the correct CORS headers in response, allowing the subsequent POST request to succeed.
